# Is this a mod_rewrite bug or am I just missing something?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I have a simple .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^[^-]*-(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^[(template)(internal)(stuff)(files)] - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/$ index.php?page=news [L]
```

And when I request for http://example.com/foo/bar everything is okay - Apache2 redirects to http://example.com/index.php?category=foo&page=bar but when I request for http://example.com/aoo/bar or http://example.com/zoo/bar (when category name begins with a or z) it doesn't get redirected - off by one error?

.htaccess tester http://htaccess.madewithlove.be also does it.

Can anyone figure it out?

EDIT:
aoo/bar - 404; boo/bar - index.php; coo/bar - index.php; doo/bar - index.php; eoo/bar - 404; foo/bar - 404; goo/bar - index.php; hoo/bar - index.php; ioo/bar - 404; joo/bar - index.php; koo/bar - 404; loo/bar - 404; moo/bar - 404; noo/bar - 404; ooo/bar - index.php; poo/bar - 404; qoo/bar - index.php; roo/bar, soo/bar, too/bar - 404; uoo/bar, voo/bar, woo/bar, xoo/bar, yoo/bar - index.php; zoo/bar - 404

Comment: Do you get error 404 ? (Just to be sure)

Comment: Yes, with aoo/bar it sends 404, but with foo/bar index.php is displayed correctly.

Comment: You can try to replace [^/\.] with [a-zA-Z] - maybe it will help. Online tester don't reproduce this error.

Comment: Unfortunately - id doesn't help - the tester above unfortunately has a bug that pattern is substituted with -. Also - foo/bar,aoo/bar aren't redirected but boo/bar is.

Comment: Figured out, that tester with your .htaccess works correctly

Comment: have you tried a different browser and/or doing `ipconfig /flushdns` in cmd then restarting your browser (just in case it works, but being cached)

Comment: Just flushed the DNS cache and used Firefox - still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second rule is FUBAR. Figure out what you want it to do, and try again.

Comment: The second rule is to match expression that contain the word templates or internal or stuff or files, and redirect them to files that I already have on my server. If expression doesn't match - redirect everything else to index.php

Comment: Corrected it to ^(template|internal|stuff|files)